# Control (or avoid?) CTE alias in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alias, common-table-expression

I've been trying to implement a simple "count to three" recursive CTE (common table expression) in SQLAlchemy 1.4. The native SQL version is

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE my_cte (i)
AS (
    SELECT 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT i + 1 FROM my_cte WHERE i < 3
)
SELECT i FROM my_cte ORDER BY i;
```

which returns

```
 i
--
 1
 2
 3
```

My initial attempt to translate to SQLAlchemy (Core) based on one of the examples [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.SelectBase.cte) was

```py
my_cte = (
    select(literal_column("1").label("i"))
    .cte(name="my_cte", recursive=True)
)
my_cte_alias = my_cte.alias()
my_cte = my_cte.union_all(
    select(
        literal_column("my_cte.i + 1"),
    )
    .where(my_cte_alias.c.i < 3)
)
stmt = select(my_cte.c.i).order_by(my_cte.c.i)
with engine.begin() as conn:
    result = conn.execute(stmt).fetchall()
    print(result)
```

but it gave me the (very helpful!) error

```
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "my_cte"
LINE 2: (SELECT 1 AS i UNION ALL SELECT my_cte.i + 1 
                                        ^
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the table alias "anon_1".
```

Indeed, I needed to change my second `literal_column()` to use `anon_1` instead of `my_cte`

```py
my_cte = (
    select(literal_column("1").label("i"))
    .cte(name="my_cte", recursive=True)
)
my_cte_alias = my_cte.alias()
my_cte = my_cte.union_all(
    select(
        literal_column("anon_1.i + 1"),
    )
    .where(my_cte_alias.c.i < 3)
)
stmt = select(my_cte.c.i).order_by(my_cte.c.i)
with engine.begin() as conn:
    result = conn.execute(stmt).fetchall()
    print(result)
```

and that worked. However, it would be nice to avoid the "anon_1" alias, or at least be in control of the alias that gets used in case a more complex circumstance might have other "anon_x" aliases that could mess up the works.

Can somebody suggest how I might do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLAlchemy's [CTE alias](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/selectable.html?highlight=alias#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.CTE.alias) accepts a name argument which can be used to reference the alias elsewhere:

```py
...
# Name the alias.
my_cte_alias = my_cte.alias("my_alias")
my_cte = my_cte.union_all(
    select(
        literal_column("my_alias.i + 1"),  # <- use the name here to refer to the alias.
    )
    .where(my_cte_alias.c.i < 3)
)
...
```