# How to perform a recursive query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, sqlmodel

I have a database of companies in a hierarchical structure where all the companies are in the same table but each refer to a parent company that is referenced in a `parent_id` column. This value matches their respective parent company's `company_id`.

The pydantic model basically looks like this:

```py
class Company(SQLModel, table=True):
    __tablename__ = "companies"

    company_id: str = Field(primary_key=True)
    parent_id: str = Field(
        foreign_key="Company.company_id",
        index=True
        )
    company_name: str = Field(index=True)
    company_type: str = Field(index=True)
```

The parent-child relationship can go down three levels deep, and each level has a different `company_type`, if it matters.

I want to SELECT a company by `company_name` and in the same response get all of its children and grandchildren (that are linked by their respective `company_id` and `parent_id` values).

I think using SQL one would use a "subquery" or a "self join", not sure which one is recommended and more performant. With regular SQL self-join I tested this:

```sql
SELECT C2.* FROM companies C1, companies C2 WHERE C1.company_name = 'xyz ltd.' AND C2.parent_id = C1.company_id;
```

and the response includes the children, but only the first level.

How can I perform this query (but retrieving all three levels of depth) using SQLModel or SQLAlchemy?

Comment: The SQL `select` statement offers no way to do recursion to an indefinite depth.

Comment: How about a defined depth? I'm thinking 3 levels would be sufficient for my case.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66895692/2144390 https://stackoverflow.com/a/66906504/2144390

Comment: What about defining an originator field with the id of the first parent? Then if you have the originator id you can select all member records of the family at all levels?